# How to use ScollView inside RadListView

Tags: angular, nativescript, scrollview, radlistview

I am creating nativescript angular app. I would like to add ScrollView in RadListView (ListView) item template to read description. But ScrollView is not working because RadListView overtakes scroll event.

Comment: Did you try nested scrollview plugin?

Comment: No, is it in NS documentation?

Comment: It's a plugin, you may goggle it or just search at market place

Comment: Thanks. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Android needs a special component ([NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView)) for nesting ScrollView which is implemented by [nativescript-nested-scrollview](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-nested-scrollview) plugin.